# Is there a way of solving this system of ODEs, implicitly or explicitly, $\dot x=x^3+xy^2, \dot y=2y^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

System: $\dot x=x^3+xy^2, \dot y=2y^3$

I have not got a lot of ideas of solving this explicitly and so I thought the most logical way is to express both $x,y$ as a function of $t.$

I attacked the second equation, which gives me $y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-4t+D}}$ for some constant $D$ then I plugged this back in $\dot x$ and so I got:

$$\dot x=x^3+\frac{x}{-4t+D}$$

Now I am really stuck, maybe there is a trick I am not seeing?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3Dx%5E3%2Bx%2F%28d-4t%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now treat the remaining equation as Bernoulli equation,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x^{-2}=-2\left(1+\frac{x^{-2}}{D-4t}\right)
$$
which is a linear first order DE in $x^{-2}$ and can thus be solved with relative ease.